# Obtener atributos consistentes desde DynamoDB a un único elemento a través del Alexa SDK

Tags: dynamodb, alexa

Estoy desarrollando una Skill para Alexa con el SDK Kit con NodeJs. Lo que busque es que la skill se conecte a una base de datos alojada en DynamoDB de forma que obtenga los mensajes de este modo. Ya he logrado que la Skill guarde datos a en una tabla y que obtenga dichos datos a través del DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter, sin embargo el elemento donde guarda (y por consiguiente luego obtiene) estos datos es el id del usuario, de forma que si otro usuario hiciera un Intent, ese usuario no obtendría información debido a que se encontraría en otro elemento de la tabla de DynamoDB. Ya he investigado demasiado y no encuentro respuesta a como apuntar TODAS las peticiones, independientemente del usuario a un único elemento de la base de datos. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Este es mi código:

```
//Importación del SDK de Alexa
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');

//Handler del LauchRequest para la apertura de la Skill
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput){
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(WELCOME_MESSAGE)
      .reprompt(HELP_MESSAGE)
      .withSimpleCard(SKILL_NAME, WELCOME_MESSAGE_CARD)
      .getResponse();

  }
};

//Handler  para el GetNewFactIntent para pedir información a la skill
const GetNewFactHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return (request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    && request.intent.name === 'GetNewFactIntent');
  },
  //Función asíncrona para la conexión a DynamoDB
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    var random = getRandomNum();
    console.log("Numero aleatorio: " + random);
    const attributes = await handlerInput.attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes();
    //Verificación de si el Intent cumple o no con los slots necesarios para considerarse un GetNewFactIntent válido
    if(!slotIsMatched(handlerInput)) {
        console.log("Matched: " + slotIsMatched(handlerInput));
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(GET_FACT_MESSAGE_EMPTY)
          .reprompt(HELP_MESSAGE)
          .getResponse();
    }
    console.log("Matched: " + slotIsMatched(handlerInput));
    const fact = attributes.consejos[random];
    console.log("Tips: " + fact);
    const speechOutput = GET_FACT_MESSAGE_RANDOM + fact;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechOutput)
    .withShouldEndSession(false)
    .withSimpleCard(SKILL_NAME, fact)
    .getResponse();
  }
};

//Handler para ayuda de la skill
const HelpHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(HELP_MESSAGE)
    .reprompt(HELP_REPROMPT)
    .getResponse();
  },
};

//Handler para salida de la skill
const CancelHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(CANCEL_MESSAGE)
    .withShouldEndSession(false)
    .getResponse();
  },
};

//Handler para salida de la skill
const StopHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(STOP_MESSAGE)
    .getResponse();
  },
};

//Handler para terminar sesión en la skill
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  },
};

//Handler de manejo de errores de la skill
const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(ERROR_MESSAGE)
    .reprompt(ERROR_MESSAGE_REPROMPT)
    .getResponse();
  },
};

//Mensajes de la skill
const SKILL_NAME = 'Nombre de mi Skill';
const WELCOME_MESSAGE = 'Bienvenido a mi Skill.';
const WELCOME_MESSAGE_CARD = 'Contenido de la tarjeta.';
const GET_FACT_MESSAGE_RANDOM = 'Aquí tienes un tip. ';
const GET_FACT_MESSAGE_EMPTY = 'No he entendido tu petición. Inténtalo de nuevo.';
const ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Lo siento, se ha producido un error.';
const ERROR_MESSAGE_REPROMPT = 'Se ha producido un error.';
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'Puedes decir Dame un Tip. ¿Cómo puedo ayudarte?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = '¿Necesitas ayuda?. Puedes decir Tip. ¿Cómo puedo ayudarte?';
const CANCEL_MESSAGE = 'Vale!';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Hasta luego.';

/* ---------------------------------------------- FUNCIONES -------------------------------------------------- */

//Obtener un valor aleatorio
function getRandomNum(){
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51);
  return randomNum;
}

//Función para verificar que los slots del Intent están incluidos
function slotIsMatched(handlerInput){
    let slot = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Tip;
    if (slot &&
        slot.resolutions &&
        slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0] &&
        slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].status &&
        slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].status.code &&
        slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].status.code &&
        slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].status.code === 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

//Constructores
const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();

//Exportación de los Handler de cada uno de los Intent
exports.handler = skillBuilder
.addRequestHandlers(
  LaunchRequestHandler,
  GetNewFactHandler,
  HelpHandler,
  CancelHandler,
  StopHandler,
  SessionEndedRequestHandler
  )
  .withAutoCreateTable(true)
  .withTableName('Tips')
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

En la última parte estoy definiendo la tabla de la cuál estoy sacando mi información, sin embargo el SDK crea automaticamente un elemento con el Id del usuario que está utilizando la SKill, ¿Existe alguna forma de que la Skill apunte sólo a un elemento especifico? De antemano gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer si quieres seguir utilizando el [DynamoDB Persistence Adapter](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Managing-Attributes.html#persistenceadapter) del SDK de Alexa pero guardar datos de forma global (por skill) en vez de por user id es cambiar el PartitionKeyGenerator.

Este define que se usa como primary key en la tabla. Si lo cambias a que se use el skill id en vez del user id (se usa por default) obtienes persistencia de attributos a nivel skill.

Puedes ver un ejemplo completo mio [aquí](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/70c979f671660fea811ccfb63801f936), especialmente [esta sección](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/70c979f671660fea811ccfb63801f936#file-index-js-L7) del código.